# Acces private static member variable in namespace from another class C++

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

I have a problem. In the following example, there is a static private member variable called `private_b` of class `A` inside namespace `a`. And then I'm trying to access that variable from class `B`, which I have declared to be a `friend` of class `A`, but it doesn't work, with a compile error from GCC:

> error: ‘B* a::A::private_b’ is private within this context

```
class B;

namespace a {
    class A {
    private:
        static B* private_b;

        friend class B;
    };

    B* A::private_b = nullptr;
}

class B {
public:
    void foo() {
        B* foo = a::A::private_b;  // Error here
    }
};
```

I don't understand why I can't access it, and how to get around this problem. I really want class `A` to be inside that namespace, and class `B` doesn't make sense to be inside that namespace. I searched for this on the internet, but couldn't find this exact case, or couldn't find a solution for this case.

Comment: Violating encapsulation is a drastic design decision

Comment: Well, in my case class A and B are somewhat related and they are in the same cpp file in my library code. They are both used by the user code. Some data being private to user code but public in library code is not bad design, it is necessary IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`friend class B;` declared friendship with `B` in the same namespace `a`. You may want `friend class ::B;`.

Note, `friend class B;` does not refer to the global forward declaration `class B`, it has own forward declaration `class B` after the keyword `friend`.

Comment: Or just `friend B;` (with the forward declaration)

Comment: Wow... I would have never solved this problem on my own. But the solution makes total sense. Thank you.